# htaccess : How to replace string with special character?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect the following URL according to the following logic :

```
Input  : https://www.example.com/blablabla,?trx_id=TX-23
Output : https://www.example.com/blablabla,TX-23
```

The rule is always remove the string : **?trx_id=**

I tried the following but it it's not working. It's seems like it's related to special characters

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)?trx_id=(.+)$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^trx_id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1%1 [QSD,R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. To match the query string you need a *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

`%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the preceding *CondPattern* (ie. the value of the `trx_id` URL parameter).